# .NET Framework 4.0 installation, change drive

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Is it possible to install .NET Framework 4.0 on another drive than C:?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. But only if your Windows installation is already on that drive.

.NET is closely integrated into Windows and will always install into %SystemRoot%.

Comment: @NoonSilk: .NET is installed on the same drive as Windows. If you want .NET on a non-C: drive then install Windows on another drive.